# How add Bitbucket artifact in Spinnaker?

Tags: spinnaker

I was watching a demo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lyv1qTet-mY on the official Armory youtube channel and found an example of how to add different types of artifacts:

[image: screenshot from the video]

but in my case when I open the same menu there are only 3 types of artifacts:
[image: screenshot from locally running spinnaker]

**Am I missing something or it is a bug?**

Answer (score 1):

Each artifact shuould be enabled using hal.

See documentation - https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/halyard/commands/#hal-config-artifact